# Ctrl-a echoes "^A" in Terminal.app

Tags: terminal.app, macbook-pro

On a brand new MacBook Pro, the keyboard doesn't seem to act as expected for Terminal.app. I'm expecting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to be home and end functions, but I just get "^A" and "^E" echoed to the terminal. How can I get these working on the MacBook Pro?

Terminal 2.1.1 ; Snow Leopard ; MacBookPro6,2

Comment: What application are you running inside the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Try manually setting your editing mode to `emacs` with the following line:

```
set -o emacs
```

You can also try this one (and save to `~/input.rc` to make it persistent):

```
set editing-mode emacs
```

You can also set additional key bindings in `.inputrc` that may not be working by default:

```
# Delete key
"\e[3~": delete-char

# Home and end
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line   # fixed syntax error in this line

# Ctrl+arrow cursor movement
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word

# History completion
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

Some other useful settings to include in this file:

```
# Case-insensitive completion
set completion-ignore-case on

# Bell style
set bell-style none

# Show ambiguous completions with one tab
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```